# Stuck with webpack HMR configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to correctly setup webpacks HMR, I'm developing a small app in order to learn how to use Redux in a React application.

I ran into a problem with webpack and the HMR plugin, when implementing the `module.hot.accept` function everything seems to work fine, but I've noticed it that when I modify a dependency of my `App` component it only re-renders the view when I don't pass any dependency argument to `module.hot.accept` as specified in webpack's docs.

This is what the documentation says I should do:

```
module.hot.accept(
  dependencies, // Either a string or an array of strings
  callback // Function to fire when the dependencies are updated
)
```

This is what I'm trying to do, this doesn't work.

```
module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
})
module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
  // Reconfigure the store
})
```

This one works

```
module.hot.accept(() => {
  // Render function
})
```

So let's say my `App` component, the one I render as child of the `<Provider>` imports a `Header` component and just renders like so:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
  </div>
)
```

then if I edit `Header` the browser will only re-render the view if there's no dependency in `module.hot.accept`

The problem here is that if I don't pass any dependency it will try to reload my store object and that fires this warning: `<Provider> does not support changing 'store' on the fly`, I want to properly configure webpack so it only updates the store object when I change things on my reducers and the view when I make changes to my components or containers.

*** Edit ***
Little bit of extra info, webpack seems to be aware of updates bc it logs in console the updated modules, however doesn't rerenders anything.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const namedModules = new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin();
const hotModuleReplacement = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: './index.jsx',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['env', {'es2015': {'modules': false}}],
            'react'
          ],
          plugins: [
            'transform-object-rest-spread',
          ]
        }
      }]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '*'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    namedModules,
    hotModuleReplacement
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    host: 'localhost',
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

Thanks in advance, fine developers.

Comment: What are you putting in the `callback` for the first `module.hot.accept`?

Comment: The same reactdom render call you do in a basic react redux app, a provider with a store prop and inside the app component

Comment: I added my webpack config

Comment: Try moving `module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
  // Reconfigure the store
})`  into its own `if(module.hot)`  inside of configureStore.js

Comment: nothing happening, same warning comes out and still not re-rendering changed components with dependency specified in `module.hot.accept` in index.jsx

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/dc6cee36b5b6f8d718f2e24a249e0491) . Looks like adding the render of App to the end of the event queue via `setTimeout` is a work around.

Comment: Nothing ;-; what I find intriguing about this is the fact that it doesn't work just when I pass the dependency arg to accept, without it, it's just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the babel configuration as I thought, you need the option `modules: false` in the babel configuration so it lets webpack handle the modules, it is a noob mistake but man, it drove me crazy for days.

Turned out I was doing something wrong in this line of the babel presets:

```
['env', {'es2015': {'modules': false}}]
```

the correct configuration is:

```
['env', {modules: false}]
```